# How to paint over the ParametricPlot Ellipse?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to paint over the ellipse.
I have following

```
a = 2;
b = 1;
ellipse[a_, b_][t_] := {a*Cos[t], b*Sin[t]}
ellipse[a, b][10]
ParametricPlot[{ellipse[a, b][t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

How can i paint over this area? I was trying to use some options of parametric plot, but without success. Help please! Tnx

Comment: Try RegionPlot instead of ParametricPlot.

Comment: How can I use region plot if I have only parametric function ellipse?

Comment: Using `ParametricRegion` but for performance sake you should calculate parameters and use `Circle`.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying using ParametricRegion, and the ellipse is painted, but how to paint over the area? I have an error.

Comment: `Graphics[{LightBlue, Opacity[0.75], Disk[{0, 0}, {a, b}]}, Axes -> True]` or `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], LightBlue, Opacity[0.75], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, {a, b}]}, Axes -> True]`

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce an extruding parameter within `ParametricPlot` or `ParametricRegion`.

#### ParametricPlot:

```
ParametricPlot[r ellipse[a, b][t], {t, 0, 2π}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

#### ParametricRegion:

```
Region @ ParametricRegion[r ellipse[a, b][t], {{t, 0, 2π}, {r, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]

`ParametricPlot` is used for visualization *only*, whereas `ParametricRegion` can be used for more than just visualization -- it's a region. You can query mathematical properties like area, centroid, point membership, etc.